# Can I safely delete Parity LOG.old.* files?

Tags: parity

I'm using Parity 1.7.0 for a private Ethereum network. Parity is writing LOG files to

```
/parity/data/chains/[.....]/db/2b05[*******]/overlayrecent/db
```

such as

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    122933 Aug 14 12:59 LOG.old.1502715631877660
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    783319 Aug 14 13:52 LOG.old.1502718779823054
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   4840603 Aug 14 20:00 LOG.old.1502740871244273
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   6616424 Aug 15 09:01 LOG.old.1502787860682563
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 487013703 Sep 18 12:29 LOG.old.1505737780992739
```

Can these be deleted ?

Comment: Yes. 1.8.0+ will not create these files anymore.